# How to connect php and wamp in android

Tags: php, android, database, wamp

I want to have some data on adatabase and my application retrieves data from there. I am beginner and i do not know how to create my databas, although I have written the php script and the java code for getting those results. So I need your help in creating that databae. I am using WAMP and I have created a database. My problem is what will be the arguments of those calls:

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxpasswordxx");
```

and of this one:

```
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/hellomysql/mysqlcon.php";
```

I read somewhere that here I maust place 10.0.0.2 and my directory under C:\wamp\www where my php file is stored.

Edit: code added

This is my android code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
private void DoMain() {

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Set the text and call the connect function.  
      //call the method to run the data retreival
        getServerData(KEY_121);
}
    public static final String KEY_121 ="http://10.0.2.2:8888/example.php"; //what in here??

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {

       InputStream is = null;

       String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1970"));

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                                ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                                ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                                ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                        );
                        //Get an output to the screen
                        returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }
```

and this is my php file

```
<?php

  mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxpasswordxx"); //what in here??

  mysql_select_db("peopledata");

  $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");

  while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

          $output[]=$e;

       print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
```

?>

Comment: Have you created webservice to Retrieve or Send data?

Comment: If you mean by that, write the code in Java and in php file which does that, yes I did. My problem is that I do not know the value of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create PHP web services to access from the android Code. At the Android Side you need to look for HttpUrlConnection API.

Comment: Yes I have done this (think so, I have created a ph file for that job and also used the HttpUrlConnection API in android side). My problem is that I don't know what addresses to palce as arguments or how I can I found them.

Comment: I have added on the initial post

Comment: are you successfully able to connect to db at php side ?

Comment: I do not know. My app crashes and I see nothing on the logcat

Comment: well in this case I will suggest you to first confirm whether your server code is working fine or not. Because if there is problem at your server side then there is no meaning of checking at android code.

Comment: My server code you mean php code? Becuase this one works fine, I have checked it on other applications. My problem now is that I ma using Wamp for creating a db and I do not know what will be the argument. (In a previous app I have my db on the server of my website and the argument was something like this : http:\\mysite.com\httptools\example.php).

Comment: Yes but I do not know what will be the argument to HttpPost function call. (Sorry for not going to chat but I do not have enough rep)

Comment: when you are uploading values from android code that time you need to use DataOutputStream to write values , these  values will be passed along with HttpConnection. And whenever you want to read values from server you need DataOutputStream class. you can google it for further explanation.